# Most rational and painless way to work on the same Eclipse Android project on two different PCs

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project that I develop partly at the work pc and party at my home PC.
Export-Import-Export-IMport and so on

And every day I spend a good amount of my time trying to resolve those annoying build path and configuration issues. Today I have written two lines of code and I have wasted the rest of my time dealing with all kinds of errors you could imagine.

And this hell repeats daily.

So I thought
Could I install Eslipse ADT on a flash drive and have my workspace on the flashdrive as well, so once the configuration is set up properly, I will be able to finally concentrate on development?

I could equalize the number of drives of both my PCs so the flash drive always appears as with same drive letter, if that could be an issue?

**I really want to find a way to use the same IDE installation and the same workspace at two computers. Not two different IDE's.**

Every time my project needs a new library I have to install it on both computers and it goes to a different directory and then I have to set the project to use it and when I switch computers all settings are wrong again.

Comment: Have you considered using GitHub?

Comment: It is not the matter of project files, its the whole configuration, dependencies, classpaths, libraries, installed add-ons and whole lot of #$% that is causing me troubles :( I need to have the software AND the project files be the same all the time

Comment: Or if not Gitub, I use a local Git on Dropbox and store my project files there too.  I use a shared keystore and everything is just fine.  My Dropbox folder also gets backed up locally so I've got online backup, local backup and source control.  Lovely.

Comment: can I upload the whole eclipse there?

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't).  Just set your workspace folder location to Dropbox.  Each PC has it's own copy of Eclipse.  The only "management" needed is to ensure that each install is updated correctly so that you are not working on a project with inconsistent IDEs.  BTW.  I used to do this with Eclipse and it was sometimes flaky, especially when it forgot how to build R.java.  I use IDEA/Android Studio now and it all just works.

Comment: ok how about my solution with the flash drive. wont it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, the project contents and the workspace are logically separate (although the default location when creating a project is place its contents in the workspace folder on disk, it doesn't have to be that way). Workspaces can not be shared between computers or users, but project contents should be. That includes all of the configuration files that make up a project (`.project`, `.classpath`, etc).

You *could* use a portable storage location like a flash drive or Dropbox to store just the project contents, and import it into each different Eclipse workspace you want to work on it in (ie, each different computer), but you'll need to always remember to Refresh the entire project every time you start to work in the workspace and there's a potential for human error to screw things up. I second the other recommendations to use some sort of source control system like cvs, svn, git, etc to check files in/out for working on different workspaces/PCs. I've done that many times with good results.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me aswell. Your problem is that Android uses some external libraries, which on every computer, are located on a different directory.

Those libraries, are referenced in a file named `project.properties`.

All you've to do, is use a GIT or a SVN as a link to your home - work. And then, add several ignores, basically:

- project.properties
- bin
- gen

This will kill any troubles.

Comment: I've got my project source checked into a repository. What I don't have checked in are the Eclipse configuration files *(`.class`, `.project` etc) or the `project.properties/bin/gen` files as said above. Check out the files and simply perform a "File > Import > Existing Android Code into Workspace". All of the Eclipse configuration should be set up automagically and your `project.properties` set up *once* and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Sergi how can I set that up?

Comment: It's not straightforward. Go google and search for GIT tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just setup you favorite IDE once then export/import your settings to another PC?

That way you'll deal with IDE config issues.

Then configure Maven build for your project so all the dependencies and stuff can be resolved automatically during the build process.

And as last step you should setup git repo for the project - Github/Bitbucket, for example.

Leaving home => push all your daily work; came home => pull all updates and continue working.

Comment: Leaving home => push all your daily work; came home => pull all updates and continue working.well this is basically the same thing like importing and exporting and the problem is the IDE itself cant figure some stuff out. I really really want to find a way to use the same IDE installation with the same workspace on two computers

Comment: @J.Kowalski actually it is more convenient because you can continue your work from any computer with Android IDE and Maven. All the dependencies, versions and settings are managed by Maven. All you need is to configure your IDEs at home and work. But this is done only **once**. To be honest I can't see the problem at all, because the situation is basically about two devs collaborating on one project: home-dev commits smth and work-dev just need to pull all home-dev's work and continue. Even simpler! Because home-dev and work-dev won't have simultaneous changes and therefore merge conflicts.

Comment: well how about the situation where I develop an action bar that needs another project in the workspace imported (appcompat v7 support) and then I have to tell eclipse that this project depends on that project and add it as a library. How is the other Eclipse installation going to know this? :/

Comment: @J.Kowalski that's why I mentioned Maven. It can handle all the deps for you. I can't understand why android devs still use "check-out-library-project-to-disk-and-manually-add-as-a-dependency" way of developing. All that's left for developer after configuring Maven pom.xml is just code his project. No more messing with android dependencies. Use maven/gradle, Luke! ;)